# Integral with logarithm in denominator

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having hard time to find following integral:

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{2x-1}{2x(1-x)}\cdot\frac{1}{2(1-x)+\log{x}}dx
\end{equation}

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [is unable to do it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(2x-1)%2F(2x(1-x)(2(1-x)%2BLog(x)))). Do you have a reason to think this has a closed form?

Comment: Any chance there is a typo in the question?  If that first $1-x$ in the denominator was not there, it would be easy.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess.  I have not worked it out.  Here is a possible way to start:

If $w = 2(1-x)+\log x$ then $dw = \left(-2+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)dx = \dfrac{1-2x}{x}dx$

The first term is $\dfrac{-dw}{2(1-x)}$

So, let $u = \dfrac{1}{2(1-x)}$ and $dv = \dfrac{-dw}{w}$.  Try integration by parts.

Comment: I am being slow here. I get what you wrote (thank you) but am unable to continue.

Comment: You are not being slow.  As I said, I have no clue if this offers a simplification at all.  It was just the first thing I spotted.  I don't know if there is a way to solve that.  Perhaps find a power series expansion for the function and integrate term-by-term?

Comment: @SlipEternal. Your change of variable looks interesting; however, it makes $$x=-\frac{1}{2} W\left(-2 e^{w-2}\right)$$ and the integrand becomes $$-\frac{1}{\left(W\left(-2 e^{w-2}\right)+2\right) \left(W\left(-2 e^{w-2}\right)+\log
   \left(-\frac{1}{2} W\left(-2 e^{w-2}\right)\right)+2\right)}$$ This problem is just awful. Cheers :)